# how to make the tablayout icon large/fit with each tab space?

Tags: android

i have made a viewpager with tablayout and i used custom view to show icon from server everything working well but the tab icons not showing fully .i uploaded a pic. how to solved this problem. i have tried with image height width match parent or static size like 50dp etc but nothing working.

my tablayout :

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/smileyShowViewPagerId"
        android:background="#ececec"
        >
      <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:id="@+id/tabLayoutId"
          android:background="#99a4b1"
          app:tabTextColor="#000000"
          app:tabMode="fixed"
          app:tabIndicatorColor="#6259b3"
          >
      </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

custom layout for icon:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageId_tabIcon"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

please can anyone help me on this issue i have searched android tutorial site and searched on google too but no solution there.
[image]

if i do icon size 24dp or else icon shows like below pic
[image]

Comment: Post your custom layout. Also set tablayout gravity to `fill`

Comment: it was set fill gravity. but did not work.
and i edited the code above

Answer (score 0):

change

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageId_tabIcon"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        />
```

To

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageId_tabIcon"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        />
```

Edit Answer Start
try this in your custom layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon2"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/icon2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:textColor="@drawable/tab_text_color"
        android:textSize="12dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and the in tour code

```
private void setupTabIcons() {

        /*tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(R.drawable.icon_tab1_config);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(R.drawable.icon_tab2_config);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(R.drawable.icon_tab3_config);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(3).setIcon(R.drawable.icon_tab4_config);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(4).setIcon(R.drawable.icon_tab5_config);*/


        View view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tab_indicator_two, null);
        ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.icon2)).setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_tab1_config);


        View view2 = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tab_indicator_two, null);
        ((ImageView) view2.findViewById(R.id.icon2)).setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_tab2_config);


        View view3 = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tab_indicator_two, null);
        ((ImageView) view3.findViewById(R.id.icon2)).setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_tab3_config);


        View view4 = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tab_indicator_two, null);
        ((ImageView) view4.findViewById(R.id.icon2)).setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_tab4_config);


        View view5 = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tab_indicator_two, null);
        ((ImageView) view5.findViewById(R.id.icon2)).setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_tab5_config);


        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setCustomView(view);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setCustomView(view2);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setCustomView(view3);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(3).setCustomView(view4);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(4).setCustomView(view5);

    }
```

Comment: i've edit the answer try this. Hope your problem resolves.

Comment: same result :( .,.,,

Comment: try one more thing just remove parent layout from custom view and try only image view in that layout and try app:tabPaddingBottom="-1dp"
            app:tabPaddingEnd="-1dp"
            app:tabPaddingStart="-1dp"
            app:tabPaddingTop="-1dp" in your tablayouts attribute

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem then I resolved it by change the padding of your tab layout:

```
app:tabPaddingEnd="2dp"
app:tabPaddingStart="2dp"
```

So TabLayout will be like this:

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
     android:id="@+id/tl_emojis"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:background="?attr/emoji_tab_background_color"
     app:tabIndicatorColor="?attr/emoji_tab_indicator_color"
     app:tabGravity="fill"
     app:tabPaddingEnd="2dp"
     app:tabPaddingStart="2dp"
     android:layout_height="50dip">
```